Example CSV Needed for Import Issue – Products Not Showing
I'm struggling with a CSV import inprestashop 8.2.0 and could really use some guidance. I've tried several approaches, including creating a simple import file (attached). The system shows that the import is completed, but nothing gets verified, and the products don’t appear.
I'm sure that the product ID is available, and the categories are correct. I even tried providing the full category path like this:
37;1;iPod Nano;home,brands,cagiva,cocis;
However, the issue persists with the same behavior.
Could anyone help me figure this out? Thanks a lot in advance!
My CSV:
37;1;iPod Nano;home;100;1;80;1;;5.5;2013-06-01;2018-12-31;RP-demo_1;RF-demo_1;Applestore;Apple;1234567890123;;1;0.6;0.2;0.4;0.068357;;;160;1;0;0;;;;;<p>New design.</p>;<p>New design.</p>;apple, ipod, nano;Meta title-Nano;Meta keywords-Nano;Meta description-Nano;iPod-Nano;In Stock;Current supply. Ordering availlable;1;2013-03-01;2013-01-01;1;1;http://localhost/prestashop/img/p/1/5/15.jpg,http://localhost/prestashop/img/p/1/5/16.jpg

enter image description here

Have you tried replacing the semicolons by commas ?

no because you must use  semi column.  comma you must use when you have many choice example many address for foto
